# GDI Screenshot, results varying on different computer

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, screenshot, gdi

I try to take a screenshot with GDI, then i use it in FFmpeg.
The screenshot works well and FFmpeg handle it without any problem.

But, on some computer, the image is not very what i want like you can see below.

[image]

Here is the code i use to init my bitmap :

```
//--
mImageBuffer = new unsigned char[mWxHxS];
memset(mImageBuffer, 0, mWxHxS);
//--
hScreenDC = GetDC(0);
hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);
//--
bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = mWidth;
bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = mHeight;
bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 24;
bi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 256;
hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hMemoryDC, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &mImageBuffer, 0, 0);
SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);
```

And here for each screenshot :

```
if(BitBlt(
    hMemoryDC,
    0,
    0,
    mWidth,
    mHeight,
    hScreenDC,
    mPx,
    mPy,
    SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT
))
```

I do not have any error running my application but this ugly image and only on some computer.
I don't know what is the difference causing that on these computer (All are Win7, Aero actived...).
I do not understand because my code follow all example i found...

Please help me !

Comment: Looks for me like you are just using rgb instead of rgba. (just the first thing that came to my mind)

Comment: Right, i use only rgb channels, but what i understand is by setting biClrUsed to 24, BitBlt convert the rgba to rgb. Moreover, on my computer the DC return 32bits but the image is Ok and i have not this problem.

Comment: How do you calculate `mWxHxS` value?

Comment: `Vcl::Forms::TMonitor* pMon = Screen->Monitors[i]; mWidth = pMon->Width; mHeight = pMon->Height; mWxHxS = mWidth*mHeight*3;`

Comment: I suppose that's the real resolution, not a monitor native resolution (not using VCL so I don't know)? From what I found in docs: *The Width property does not take into account any task bars or tool bars docked on the monitor*. Could it be that the system has the taskbar on left or right side which is afftecting the output?

Comment: I verified theses sizes and it returns the correct values (the real monitor resolution i need). What i believe, is that there is something in the pixel alignement which are different depending on the computer (maybe the graphic card implementation) and BitBlt doesnt take it in account.

Comment: `biClrUsed` should not be set to the number of bits per pixel.  It's for palette-based images that don't use all the colors in the palette.  Unless you're creating a bitmap with a palette (color table), you should set it to 0.

Comment: I correct it, but with or without it does not change anything !

Comment: Maybe you're incorrectly accounting for the padding at the end of each row when you read the data back. Then it would only manifest on monitors with certain horizontal sizes (if the horizontal size is a multiple of 4 pixels there's no padding)

Comment: Where can be this accounting ? Anyway, all screen i try my code are multiple of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finaly find the solution :

It seems that the BitBlt and StretchBlt doesnt really handle correctly the transfer between 32 to 24 bits on some computers...

Now, i use only 32bits with GDI and let FFmpeg with libswscale convert my RGBA image to a YUV format.

My changes :

```
mWidth = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
mHeight = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);
mWxHxS = mWidth*mHeight*4;

bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, mWidth, mHeight);


if(BitBlt(
    hMemoryDC,
    0,
    0,
    mWidth,
    mHeight,
    hScreenDC,
    mPx,
    mPy,
    SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT
    ) && GetDIBits(hScreenDC, hBitmap, 0, mHeight, mImageBuffer, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
    {
    return true;
    }
```

Thanks trying to help me !

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a Device-Independent-Bitmap (CreateDIBSection) then using a Device Dependent Context (CreateCompatibleDC) to work with it.  I believe you need to create a device dependent bitmap to be compatible with BitBlt, or use StretchDIBits to support device-independent image data.  The reason this works on some computers and not others is because the video driver determines the format of a device-dependent image, which may or may not be the same as the Windows definition of a device-independent image.

Here is an example of capturing an image (yes, its unnecessarily long, but still seems to contain good info): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx

And here is documentation on StretchDIBits, in case you require a DIB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145121(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you Matt, i understand what's the problem now, but i want to copy from the device context to a DIB and StrechDIBits seems to do the invert (From DIB to a rectangle) am i right ? The example in your link conserve a compatible DC like my code... So i think i need to find an context independant HDC to DIB function !

Comment: I try with CreateCompatible bitmap and use GetDIBits, but always the same results : `hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, mWidth, mHeight); if(GetDIBits(hScreenDC, hBitmap, 0, mHeight, mImageBuffer, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))`